# admob in preference screen issue

Tags: admob, preferenceactivity, preferencescreen

I am using preference screen in my app and was trying to implement AdMob.

I followed [this website](http://modian.tistory.com/entry/Android-Admob%EC%9D%84-PreferenceActivity%EC%97%90-%EA%B5%AC%ED%98%84) to add AdMob on my preference screen.

I tested my app on Galaxy Gio (320x480) Gingerbread OS 2.3.8, and Admob does not appear and rather give me a logcat like this :

```
type: “admob” afmaNotifyDt: “null” activationOverlayUrl: “null” useWebViewLoadUrl: “false”>
```

I also tested on Galaxy Grand 2 with JellyBean OS. Admob is showing, but in one class, it disappeared. Is it possible that problems happen if a class has a lot preference screen ?

Thanks

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: admob not support on mdpi device ?
i was try to add admob on my app and test it on my device but not appear